# Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration and "ClassNotFoundException: javax

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, error-handling, compiler-errors

1)When executing this error ouccred and searched and tried every solution given but any of them did work and i didnt know why. Here is my pom file :

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.2.0
 

com.wahch
todoapp
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
todoapp
Todo app

<java.version>19.0.2</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and with it this error just kept coming over and over "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter" in the pursuit of solving this error the error above appeared xd

i tried changing the versions of some dependencies as someone said in stackoverflow in someone problem but didnt change anything and for the class not found javax i tried to do run/configuration but when i tried to add a springboot app run config i didnt find it in the run config maybe because its a community edition IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem that you have here is in mixing of framework versions

To fix it you have to remove

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And also be sure that you replace all projects imports from `javax.x` to `jakarta.x`.
Because from Spring Boot 3.x and Spring Framework 6.x all `javax.x` were replaced with `jakarta.x`.

More details you can find in next one resources.
[Spring Boot 3.0 Migration](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of tomcat are you using?
javax.servlet-api 4.0.1 needs tomcat higher than 9.

or

You should check this part.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I think you can pick one.